# Searching and retrieving value from database through checkbox selection

Tags: php

I need help ... that too from scratch as now am learning php. just variable declaration i am learning.

I have created a form with 5 check boxes. when i select any 1 or any 2, 3.. or any combination, i should get the data which is already stored for that option in MySQL database.

My form is this:

```
<form method="post" action="search.php" name="search_form" onsubmit="return checkCheckBoxes(this);">
         <input type="checkbox" name="search1" value="qwerty_keypad" id="search1">QWERTY Keypad


         <input type="checkbox" name="search2" value="touch_screen" id="search2"> Touch Screen


         <input type="checkbox" name="search3" value="usb" id="search3"> SUB Drive


         <input type="checkbox" name="search4" value="mobile_tracker" id="search4">Mobile Tracker


         <input type="checkbox" name="search5" value="Backup" id="search5">Phone backup on MMC


         <input type="submit" value="Search" />         </form>
```

what i should write in search.php.

Please help me ... please
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) Can you post the relevant snippet of your database schema where this data is stored?

Comment: Hi , here is my database

Comment: Hi , here is my database  create table mobile_search (id int(5) primary key, model varchar(50), hearo_features varchar(50), type varchar(50), basics varchar(50), battery varchar(50), multimedia varchat(50), connectivity varchar(50));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array to submit the values

```
<input type="checkbox" name="search[connectivity]" value="usb" id="search3"> USB
<input type="checkbox" name="search[display]" value="touchscreen" id="search4">Touchscreen
```

Afterwards you build your query based on those values:

```
foreach($_POST['search'] as $k=> $search){
    $where[]= $k." = '".mysql_real_escape_string($search)."'";
}

$query = "Select * from table where ".implode(' AND ',$where);
```

Comment: Hi sorry for asking the samething again and again..... am very fresher and am not getting it clearly. if i select two checkboxes, then it should search whole database which matched those two values then it should display the result. so what i should give in "fiels_to_search. is it the result i wanted?

Comment: In which table field are the values to be searched?

Comment: in whole table it should search values, if the user selects usb drive as well as mobile tracker, he should get the model number whcich has both the fetaures

Comment: In which fields are those values in the table? I can't tell from your column names. In Addition: how are the values (if there are more than one per field) separated? with comma?

Comment: for each value (my checkbox values) there is a separate column in the table. only one value in a column

Comment: But in the schema you posted above I can see neither of the fields. If the fields are named the same, take a look at the updated respponse

Comment: field names are different, under that i have the entries like USB and all (as i have in checkbox). for example There is a field called Connectivity under that i have an entry USB. Sorry if i was wrongly answered and wasted your time previously.